# Adding description to WCF web service that appears in WSDL

Tags: wcf, wsdl

should it be possible to tag DataContracts, DataMembers, ServiceContracts and OperationContracts with a Description attribute, (System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute) so that those descriptions appear in the WSDL to aid the developer or so an automatic documentation generation tool like TechWriter can use them in the documentation.

I went and added descriptions to my web services but they don't appear in the WSDL.

Is there any other way to do what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [TechWriter](http://www.adivo.com/techwriter-for-web-services.aspx) relies on the descriptions being in the WSDL, you'll want to check out a WCF addon called [WCFExtras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) that can make that happen.  Instead of using attributes, WCFExtras uses the XML Comments from your source code.